# If $P(X<Y)=P(X<g(Y))$ then what could be the form of $g$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ are two continuous random variable and $$P(X<Y)=P(X<g(Y)),$$ for some convex function $g$.

Is it true that $g$ will always be a linear function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X<0$ (a negative random variable) and $Y\ge 0$ (a non-negative random variable) and $g(y)=y^2$ convex. Then $$P(X<Y)=P(X<g(Y))=1$$ and $g$ is not linear. (Or $X \sim U[0,1], Y \sim U[2,3]$ and $g(y)=y^2$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  If $X$ and $Y$ are both $(0,\infty)$ valued random variable, then what could be a counter example?

Comment: I am having difficulties to find any example of $X, Y$ on $(0, +\infty)$ that satisfies $P(X<Y)=P(X<g(Y))$ with $g\neq constant$... So, sorry. (perhaps unaccept my answer and wait for a better one. My examples are based on an extreme case in some sense...)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Since this is a answer to my initial question I am accepting the answer. I will try to solve the modified question and will post it as a new question if unable to solve after trying enough.